# Интерпретатор brainfuck и вложенные циклы

Tags: c++, g++, brainfuck

В общем я написал интерпретатор brainfuck. Когда я ввожу в него команды без вложенных циклов (типа очистки памяти `>+++++++++>++++++++>+++++++++++>+++++++[[-]<]`) то получаю "ошибку сегментирования". Вот мой интерпретатор

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

char c;
char arr[30000];
int place = 0;

void bf(string s)
{
    string cycle;
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        switch (s[i]) {
        case '>':
            place++;
            break;
        case '<':
            place--;
            break;
        case '+':
            arr[place]++;
            break;
        case '-':
            arr[place]--;
            break;
        case '.':
            cout << arr[place];
            break;
        case ',':
            cin.get(arr[place]);
            break;
        case '[':
            j = i + 1;
            while (s[j] != ']') {
                cycle += s[j];
                j++;
            }
            while (arr[place] != 0) {
                bf(cycle);
            }
            i += cycle.size();
            break;
        }
        if (place > 30000)
            place = 0;
        else if (place < 0)
            place = 30000;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string s;
    ifstream in(argv[1]);

    while (in.good()) {
        in.get(c);
        s += c;
    }
    bf(s);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: я конечно понимаю суть проблемы, но я не знаю как её разрешить:
когда он встречает еще один цикл, при записи в переменную, то после того как он встречает ']'(тот символ который завершает вложенный цикл, а не тот который он записывает в переменную) он заканчивает запись и обрубает цикл, но как решить понять не могу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А подумайте, что делает код

```
while(s[j]!=']'){
    cycle+=s[j];j++;
}
```

он не подозревает, что внутри могут быть циклы.
Можно попробовать как то так:

```
int br_counter;
case '[':
    br_counter = 0;
    while(true){
        if (s[j] == '[') br_counter++;
        if (s[j] == ']') br_counter--;
        if (br_counter == 0) break;
        cycle+=s[j];j++;
    }
    bf(cycle);
```

правда это не самое лучшее решение.

Comment: спасибо огромное, все-таки мне еще учиться и учиться

Answer (score 3):

Я реализовал так - заранее пробегаемся по програме и для каждой '[' запоминаем соответствующую ей ']' и наоборот.
Вот набросал свою реализацию, может быть вам поможет:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stack>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <map>

const size_t DATA_SIZE = 100000;
std::vector<char> DATA(DATA_SIZE, 0);
typedef std::vector<char>::iterator DataPointer;
DataPointer DP = DATA.begin();
const std::set<char>
ALLOWED_CHARS = {'<', '>', '+', '-', '.', ',', '[', ']'};
typedef std::string Program;
typedef std::string::const_iterator IP;
typedef std::map<IP, IP> JumpsMap;

Program readProgram(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    Program result;
    char c; 
    while (ifs >> c) {
        if (ALLOWED_CHARS.count(c)) {
            result.push_back(c);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

JumpsMap calculateJumps(const Program& program) {
   std::stack<IP> cycleStarts;
   JumpsMap result;
   for (IP ip = program.begin(); ip != program.end(); ++ip) {
       if (*ip == '[') {
           cycleStarts.push(ip);
       } else if (*ip == ']') {
           if (cycleStarts.empty()) {
                throw std::domain_error(
                        "Detected unexpected ']'");
           }
           result[ip] = cycleStarts.top();
           result[cycleStarts.top()] = ip;
           cycleStarts.pop();
       }
   }
   if (!cycleStarts.empty()) {
       throw std::domain_error("Detected unclosed cycle");
   }
   return result;
}

void execute(const Program& p, const JumpsMap& jm) {
    IP cur = p.begin();
    while (cur != p.end()) {
        switch (*cur) {
            case '>':
                ++DP;
                if (DP == DATA.end()) {
                    throw std::out_of_range("Data pointer out of range");
                }
                break;
            case '<':
                if (DP == DATA.begin()) {
                    throw std::out_of_range("Data pointer out of range");
                }
                --DP;
                break;
            case '+':
                ++*DP;
                break;
            case '-':
                --*DP;
                break;
            case '.':
                std::cout << *DP;
                break;
            case ',':
                std::cin >> *DP;
                break;
            case '[':
                if (*DP == 0) {
                    cur = jm.at(cur);
                } 
                break;
            case ']':
                if (*DP != 0) {
                    cur = jm.at(cur);
                }
                break;
        }
        ++cur;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " program.bf" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    try {
        Program p = readProgram(argv[1]);
        JumpsMap jm = calculateJumps(p);
        execute(p, jm);
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what();
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: извините, но я пока только догадываюсь что вы написали. я уверен, что этот код гораздо лучше, но я пока не настолько силен.

Comment: Вы знаете, что такое map? Принципиально работа моего кода почти не отличается от вашего.
Единственное различие, что при встрече '[', если data pointer указывает на 0-ую ячейку, то сразу происходит "прыжок" на ячейку в которой хранится соответствующий ']'. Аналогично и для ']'.
Задавайте вопросы, отвечу

Comment: stdexcept, stack, set, map - этого всего я не знаю(кроме stack, но я не умею его применять)